# Preferred alternative to creating a new object in Spring Webflow

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I am currently working with `Spring 3.1.2 (webflow version 2.3.1)` and I'm facing an older problem once again. The problem is creating a new object via Spring webflow. So what I'd like to do is following :

`<set name="myBean.foo" value="new Bar()"`

I did some research and found out it was a no-go. Now facing that same problem, I'm wondering if there are maybe some new facilities for this problem that I don't know about, or a preferred alternative. In the past I used a static factory for this.

In addition to Alan J Liu's response : the object needs to be initiated every time a certain transition is made (or every time a certain view is entered).

PS : [springsource](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?75778-Can-we-create-an-object-in-Spring-Web-Flow-2-expression) did not quite answer my question here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the static factory does what you need, correct? You're just seeking an alternative to that approach?

Comment: Actually I'm just wondering which is the best approach, because creating a static factory does seem a bit silly for some of the cases I've ran into. But you are correct, yes.

Comment: Understand and agree. I just wanted to clarify. I actually thought that declaring the var inside the view-state would accomplish it, but when I read the latest documentation just now, it's clear that even doing that still uses a flow-scoped instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'value' attribute accepts SpEL (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html), so you can use the 'new' operator, just make sure that you are using the fully-qualified class name. Finally, newly created objects are in flow-scope by default, but you can specify the desired scope explicitly, this is working for me:

```
<view-state id="searchScreen" view="/WEB-INF/jsp/query.view.jsp">
    <on-entry>
        <set name="flashScope.test" value="new java.util.Date()"/>
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="..." to="...">
        <evaluate expression="..."/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

Comment: Great answer, that really solves this issue! I did not know about the necessity to write fully-qualified names in this situation. I thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<var name="object1" class="my.package.Object" />
<set name="objectHolder.object" value="object1" />
```

Line one will create a new object via the constructor, and the second line will set it as a variable object in objectHolder class (via setter).

OR:

```
<set name="objectHolder.object" value="objectFactory.createObject()" />
```

Where:
    public Object createObject{ return new Object() }

Comment: It would initially, but maybe I should have added a key piece of information in my question: the 'new' object needs to be initiated every time a certain transition is made. So this would work the first time, but would then re-use that same object...

Comment: So in line 2 set the value="factory.createObject()" so you get a new object everytime you set the objectHolder.object.

Comment: As much as I don't like to program in xml files, I do think it would be a shortcoming of SpEL if this is currently the best/only solution. It is very weird to be creating static factories for objects that do not contain any logic, or that much information for that matter. I'm talking about plain and simple model objects right now. Anyway, thanks for your input. It seems like we share the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a Java factory for your objects. While you can create an object like:

```
<on-entry>
        <set name="flashScope.test" value="new java.util.Date()"/>
</on-entry>
```

there is a problem with refactoring, if you use your object. If you move/rename your object, your XML will be broken. Instead create a factory like:

```
@Component("webflowBeanFactory")
public class WebflowBeanFactory {    
    public static YourObject yourObjectBean(Object argument) {
        return new YourObject(argument);
    }
}
```

and then call it from webflow like:

```
<on-entry>
        <set name="flashScope.yourObject" value="webflowBeanFactory.yourObjectBean(anyVariable)"/>
</on-entry>
```